# React native Fetching and using usestate for dependant data items

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to fetch 3 dependent data items from 3 APIs. By that I mean that I fetch element a, b and c and c is dependent on b and b ia dependant on a. When I fetch the data, I need to check it is not null firstly before fetching the next one then I either try to fetch it again if it ia null or fetch the next data item. Now, I have a problem implementing this. I store item "a" in a state using useState and then strange things happen. When the data is updated in "a" for example, it becomes null then it valid data is fetched then it becomes null again. So, when I fetch "b", I cannot be sure whether "a" is not null or not.

I tried to work with useEffect to make sure that states are updated, but I still get strange behaviour.

```
const [item1, setItem1] = useState(null);

const [item2, setItem2] = useState(null);


useEffect(() =>{
if(item1==null) {
FetchItem1();
}
}, []) 

useEffect(() =>{
if(item2==null) {
FetchItem2();
}
}, [item2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
const [item1, setItem1] = useState(null);

const [item2, setItem2] = useState(null);

useEffect(() =>{
  if(item1==null) {
    FetchItem1();
    // update the result with setItem1()
  }
}, []) 

useEffect(() =>{
  // As item2 is dependant on item1, you need to check whether item1 is there or not null.
  if(item1 && item2==null) {
    FetchItem2();
    // update item2 with setItem2()
  }
}, [item1, item2])
```

You can do the same for item3.